# Comparison of two HTML Files in C#.net

Tags: c#, .net

can any one help me out of this?
i m actually making a crawler which can fetch words from website & store whole page as html file
but now i want to compare new crawl with old one i.e old html file with new one & find out the differences among them that how many words are deleted or inserted?
so basically i want c# code or example which can help me to find out how two html files are compare?

i have try with XmlDiff

but it don't work for me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at this project: [DiffPlex](http://diffplex.codeplex.com). It produce the difference line based/word based/charachter based or even with a custom pluggable strategy.